# How do I rename all files index.php containing a certain folder in the path?

Tags: bash, rename

I want to rename all wordpress admin index files into index_disabled in the folder

```
/var/www/
```

I need a script like

```
find /var/www/ -path '*wp-admin/index.php' -exec mv {} $(dirname {})/index_disabled
```

but this doesen't work like this

the problem is this: [How do i use the {} operator in find execution inside exec](https://serverfault.com/questions/500122/how-do-i-use-the-operator-twice-in-find-exec)

my bash skills are not good enough to complete this ;)

Comment: The bash code will be nearly trivial but you have to explain what exactly you want. What do "all files like" and "$(locate wp-admin/index.php)" stand for? "All files in a known directory"? "All *.php files"? "A directory that needs to be found"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **find** command for this:

```
find /var/www/ -path '*wp-admin/index.php' -exec mv -v {} {}_disabled \;
```

This will rename all files to {old_name}_disabled.

Comment: this doesent work: Warnung:  `Unix Dateinamen enthalten gewöhnlich keine Schrägstriche (anders als Pfadbezeichnungen).` in english something with slash in filenames

Comment: for finding a path and file combination you will indeed need to use the -path argument to find instead of the -name argument. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: you forgot the -path argument?

Comment: ok, so i need something like this: `find /var/www/ -path '*wp-admin/index.php' -exec mv {} $(dirname {})/index_disabled` but that doesent work ;) the problem is this: http://serverfault.com/questions/500122/how-do-i-use-the-operator-twice-in-find-exec

Comment: I have it!!! `find /var/www/ -path '*wp-admin/index.php' -exec mv {} {}_disabled \;` thanks!!! ;)