# How do i use the {} operator in find execution inside exec

Tags: bash, find, search-and-replace

I tried this bash command:

```
find /var/www/ -path '*wp-admin/index.php' -exec mv {} $(dirname {})/index_disabled
```

But the second `{}` is not executed.

It results in just `./index_disabled` instead.

How can I use the found parameter twice in the execute command?

Comment: the problem is in $(dirname {})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple for loop to solve this.

```
for f in $(find /var/www/ -path '*wp-admin/index.php'); do mv $f $(dirname $f)/index_disabled; done
```

Comment: Also a pipe to `while read` would do the job

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is not that it's not interpreted twice, as doing

```
find . -type f -exec echo {} {} \;
```

will show.  The problem is that `{}` can't be used as an argument to a function, as you're trying to.  In my (limited) experience, if you want to get clever with `find` and the contents of `{}`, you'll need to write a shell script that is invoked from `find`, that takes `{}` as its one and only argument, and that does the clever things inside that script.

Here's an example clever script:

```
[me@risby tmp]$ cat /tmp/clever.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 $(dirname $1)/index_disabled
```

Here's me using it with find, and the last few lines of the results:

```
[me@risby tmp]$ find . -type f -exec /tmp/clever.sh {} \;
[...]
./YubiPAM-1.1-beta1/stamp-h1 ./YubiPAM-1.1-beta1/index_disabled
./YubiPAM-1.1-beta1/depcomp ./YubiPAM-1.1-beta1/index_disabled
./YubiPAM-1.1-beta1/INSTALL ./YubiPAM-1.1-beta1/index_disabled
```

As you can see, if I replaced `echo` in the shellscript with `mv`, I'd get the desired result.

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem. But how could I solve this without having to write an extra shell script? for the next time ;)

Comment: Beats me; I run into this problem seldom enough that I take the "noddy shell script" route when I do.  It also has the handy advantage that, by using `echo` in place of the real function, **you can check what it's going to do before running it for real**, thus avoiding the sort of "*I just blew away 375 important files, I have no backups, how do I undelete*" question that gets asked depressingly often around these parts.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use the `xargs` command and a little trick:

```sh
$ find /var/www/ -path '*wp-admin/index.php' | xargs -i sh -c 'mv {} $(dirname {})/index_disabled'
```

Comment: I get the error `xargs: %: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden`

Comment: You may have a typo. If not try: xargs -i sh -c 'mv {} $(dirname {})/index_disabled' in place.

Comment: this works, you should update your answer, then this will be the solution to the question

Comment: can you please explain why this works?